# CSS: Understanding the padding statement

Tags: css

I am trying to wrap my head around the padding statement - I've seen a few uses of it that makes sense to me, but recently I came across this implementation:

```
padding: 30px 0;
```

Now I understand the first parameter, 30px, but what does the 0 represent?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This basically `0 => 0px`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`padding`](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#padding-properties) is a shorthand property of

- `padding-top`
- `padding-right`
- `padding-bottom`
- `padding-left`

It allows multiple values:

> If there is only one component value, it applies to all sides. If
>   there are two values, the top and bottom paddings are set to the first
>   value and the right and left paddings are set to the second. If there
>   are three values, the top is set to the first value, the left and
>   right are set to the second, and the bottom is set to the third. If
>   there are four values, they apply to the top, right, bottom, and left,
>   respectively.

Therefore, `padding: 30px 0` sets `padding-top` and `padding-bottom` to `30px`, and `padding-right`  and `padding-left` to `0`

Comment: Wow, super explanation! Many thanks, will give you answer when I can (10 minutes) - Very helpful :)

Answer (score 4):

Instead of defining padding as `padding-top`, `padding-bottom`, `padding-right` or `padding-left`, developer defines them as below,

```
div{
padding : 10px 10px 10px 10px /*top right bottom left*/
}
```

(or)

```
div{
padding : 10px 0px; /*10px is for top and bottom, whereas 0px is for right and left*/  
}
```

Answer (score 3):

So, here is how it works:

If the padding property has four values:

```
padding: 25px 50px 75px 100px;
```

the top padding is `25px`, right padding is `50px`, bottom padding is `75px` and left padding is `100px`.

If the padding property has three values:

```
padding: 25px 50px 75px;
```

top padding is `25px`, right and left paddings are `50px` and bottom padding is `75px`.

If the padding property has two values:

```
padding: 25px 50px;
```

top and bottom paddings are `25px` and right and left paddings are `50px`.

If the padding property has one value:

```
padding: 25px;
```

all four paddings are `25px`.

Comment: You can wrap parts of code in your answer with **``**  so it will highlight as a code, making it more readable. But that a great answer